# Line Chart with different line colors in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, charts, line

I am working on line chart in d3. I got stuck as I am new in d3. I need help.

I have data set of 4 Parties ( Congress, BJP, Janta Dal, Indian National Congress) in which i need to display data of GDP and GNI.

The value of GDP in xAxis and GNI yAxis.

And want to plot single line as per given data but in different colors.

```html
<svg  class="svgid" width="1300" height="600"></svg>
```

**Javascript**

```js
g.selectAll("path")     
     .data(data) 
 .enter().append("line")
 
   .attr("stroke-width", "10")
  .style("stroke",  function(d) {            
            if (d.Party === "BJP") {return "#f58221"}  
             else if (d.Party === "Janata Dal") {return "#008000"}
    else if (d.Party === "Congress") {return "#ffffff"}
 else if (d.Party === "Indian National Congress") {return "#004489"}
    else    { return "black" }
 ;})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return x(d.GDP)} )
        .attr("y2",  function(d) { return y(d.GNI)});
```

CSV data:

```js
[
 {
   "GDP": 266.502,
   "GNI": 340,
   "Year": 1991,
   "Name": "P. V. Narasimha Rao",
   "Party": "Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 284.364,
   "GNI": 340,
   "Year": 1992,
   "Name": "P. V. Narasimha Rao",
   "Party": "Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 257.57,
   "GNI": 320,
   "Year": 1993,
   "Name": "P. V. Narasimha Rao",
   "Party": "Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 322.91,
   "GNI": 340,
   "Year": 1994,
   "Name": "P. V. Narasimha Rao",
   "Party": "Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 355.476,
   "GNI": 360,
   "Year": 1995,
   "Name": "P. V. Narasimha Rao",
   "Party": "Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 387.656,
   "GNI": 400,
   "Year": 1996,
   "Name": "H. D. Deve Gowda",
   "Party": "Janata Dal"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 410.32,
   "GNI": 410,
   "Year": 1997,
   "Name": "I. K. Gujral",
   "Party": "Janata Dal"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 415.731,
   "GNI": 410,
   "Year": 1998,
   "Name": "Atal Bihari Vajpayee",
   "Party": "BJP },
 {
   "GDP": 452.7,
   "GNI": 430,
   "Year": 1999,
   "Name": "Atal Bihari Vajpayee",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 462.147,
   "GNI": 440,
   "Year": 2000,
   "Name": "Atal Bihari Vajpayee",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 478.965,
   "GNI": 450,
   "Year": 2001,
   "Name": "Atal Bihari Vajpayee",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 508.069,
   "GNI": 450,
   "Year": 2002,
   "Name": "Atal Bihari Vajpayee",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 599.593,
   "GNI": 510,
   "Year": 2003,
   "Name": "Atal Bihari Vajpayee",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 699.689,
   "GNI": 600,
   "Year": 2004,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 808.901,
   "GNI": 700,
   "Year": 2005,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 920.317,
   "GNI": 790,
   "Year": 2006,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1201,
   "GNI": 920,
   "Year": 2007,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1187,
   "GNI": 1000,
   "Year": 2008,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1324,
   "GNI": 1110,
   "Year": 2009,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1657,
   "GNI": 1220,
   "Year": 2010,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1823,
   "GNI": 1380,
   "Year": 2011,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1828,
   "GNI": 1480,
   "Year": 2012,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 1857,
   "GNI": 1520,
   "Year": 2013,
   "Name": "Man Mohan Singh",
   "Party": "Indian National Congress"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 2039,
   "GNI": 1560,
   "Year": 2014,
   "Name": "Narendra Modi",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 2102,
   "GNI": 1600,
   "Year": 2015,
   "Name": "Narendra Modi",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 2274,
   "GNI": 1680,
   "Year": 2016,
   "Name": "Narendra Modi",
   "Party": "BJP"
 },
 {
   "GDP": 2601,
   "GNI": 1800,
   "Year": 2017,
   "Name": "Narendra Modi",
   "Party": "BJP"
 }
]
```

Comment: Claudia - please post whatever code you have tried - without code this question is at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 0):

First you can determine the x and y scales for your data:

```
xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.GDP))
  .range([0, width]);

yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.GNI))
  .range([height, 0]);
```

If you want a separate line for each of the political parties, then you probably need to prepare a different data array for each party by filtering the original data.

```
const congress = data.filter(d => d.Party === 'Congress');
const bjp = data.filter(d => d.Party === 'BJP');
...
etc
```

Then you can build the line generator that can be used to draw each line:

```
const lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d))
  .y(d => yScale(d));
...
etc
```

Then you can add each line to the chart:

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(congress)
  .style('stroke', 'darkgreen')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .attr('d', lineGenerator);
...
etc
```